# Filter angular table data by selecting dropdown values

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, filter

Here I have a JSON array

```
demoList = [ 
  { name:"asian003", model:"hyper20", class:"selina0127" },
  { name:"asian003", model:"hyper21", class:"selina0127" },
  { name:"norva", model:"hyper21", class:"gowri.14" },
  { name:"sparks007", model:"NNc22", class:"gowri.14" },
  { name:"asian003", model:"NNc22", class:"selina0127" }
]
```

This array showing in an HTML table using Angular. I want to add dropdowns separately such as **name** dropdown, **model** dropdown, **class** dropdown. When I select drop-down values I want to filter table records.

For example, if I select `asian003` from **name** and `selina0127` from **class** and do not select the value **model** dropdown, I want to get the below result into the table preview

```
demo1List = [
  {name:"asian003",model:"hyper20",class:"selina0127"},
  {name:"asian003",model:"hyper21",class:"selina0127"},
  {name:"asian003",model:"NNc22",class:"selina0127"}
]
```

Comment: pls consider this => For example, if I select `asian003` from **name** and `selina0127` from **class** and do not select the value **model** dropdown, I want to get the below result into the table preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and bind one property to each dropdown. Then on any dropdown change, you can call `filter_demo_list()` function:

```js
const demoList = [ 
  { name:"asian003", model:"hyper20", class:"selina0127" },
  { name:"asian003", model:"hyper21", class:"selina0127" },
  { name:"norva", model:"hyper21", class:"gowri.14" },
  { name:"sparks007", model:"NNc22", class:"gowri.14" },
  { name:"asian003", model:"NNc22", class:"selina0127" }
]

public table_data;
public selected_name;
public selected_class;
public selected_model;

filter_demo_list() {
  this.table_data = demoList;
  if (this.selected_name) this.table_data.filter((item)=> item.name === this.selected_name);
  if (this.selected_class) this.table_data.filter((item)=> item.class  === this.selected_class);
  if (this.selected_model) this.table_data.filter((item)=> item.model === this.selected_model);
}
```

Comment: pls consider this => For example, if I select `asian003` from **name** and `selina0127` from **class** and do not select the value **model** dropdown, I want to get the below result into the table preview

Comment: My code covers that logic. As you can see, if `this.selected_model` is not selected, the last `if` condition will not be executed and the filter by `model` won't be applied.

Comment: I made some modifications. The code is worked.